# JQuery cycle not working in firefox & ie, works in chrome & safari

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-cycle

I've been hunting around for a solution for this and cant find one, looked at people who have had similar problems but fixes aren't working for me. Basically I am using jquery cycle to display 5 images as a background at the top of the site, it works in chrome and safari but not in firefox or ie.

I've spent hours trying to fix it but I've had no joy. The current state of the code is available at: http://beta.immbudden.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed one thing, if you change following CSS then its gonna work:

default one:

```
#slide {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

working one:

```
#slide {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: your a lifesaver! I thought it was going to end up being something minor, all sorted now though. many thanks amigo!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the error `$ is not defined` in Firefox. Try making jQuery the first script you load on the page, and see if that solves it.

Comment: tried it, but didn't work, answer below got it working though, cheers anyway amigo!